# Error using postgres JSONB query with jdbctemplate

Tags: jdbctemplate, postgresql-9.5

PostgresSql Query

```
SELECT json_data FROM employee where json_data -> 'employee' @> '{"name":"Aman"}'
```

This query works fine when run in postgres. But when run with jdbctemplate, it throws an error.

Java Code

```
String sql="SELECT json_data FROM employee where json_data -> 'employee' @> '{\"name\":\"?\"}'";

List<Map<String, Object>> emp = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,param);
```

On encountering the last line of the code,it throws an error:-
The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException.

It is not able to substitute the '?' placeholder.

Comment: You probable need to use `sql = " .... @> ?` then pass `"{\"name\":\"foo\"}"` as the parameter

Comment: I need to pass the parameter at runtime to substitute that placeholder '?' from the jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql,param);